# How to use a new function added to a GitHub-hosted toolbox in Pycharm installed via pip

Tags: python, git, github, pip, pycharm

How can I use a newly added function in the master branch of a GitHub-hosted toolbox that I originally installed using "pip install .."? I am trying to access the new function directly in Pycharm, but it is not appearing even after I tried upgrading the toolbox using the command

```
pip install --upgrade
```

in the terminal.